# at a Youtube tutorial video a Javascript simple-beginner project that I don't understand how it works

Tags: javascript

How is this colour starts from the Orangered? Isn't that supposed to starts from the Blue?

[youtube video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIjAGcMh3QA&list=PLtMugc7g4GaqAVDZwQ_t1H6500ZGJzOgW&index=1)

html code `<button id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Click Me!</button>`

js code

```
var colors = ["Orangered","Blue","Yellow","Green","Orange", "Cyan","DodgerBlue", "Violet", "Navy", "Purple", "YellowGreen", "OrangeRed", "SlateBlue", "Salmon", "Crimson", "HotPink", "Magenta"];
var index = 0;

document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
  if(index > colors.length - 1)
    index = 0;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[index++];  
});
```

Comment: Since the ++ operator is on the right, *index* is incremented after being evaluated

Comment: Wow i didn't know anything about this speciality of the ++ operator. Thank you man!  That was what i looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided starts with the color "Orangered" because of the initial value of the index variable, which is set to 0 at the beginning:

```
var index = 0;
```

Here's how it works step by step:

Initially, index is 0, so it starts with the first color in the colors array, which is "Orangered."

When you click the button, it sets the background color to "Orangered" and increments index to 1.

The next time you click the button, it sets the background color to "Blue" (the color at index 1) and increments index to 2.

This process continues, cycling through the colors in the colors array one by one until it reaches the end of the array.

Once index becomes greater than or equal to colors.length (the length of the colors array), it wraps around to 0, effectively starting the cycle over from "Orangered."

Comment: @RaveOnTime if my response satisfied You, You can mark it as accepted so others can easily look it up.